S-bend composed of 2 arcs and a connecting line
I am trying to create "S-bends" in piping using 2 arcs and a straight connecting piece (call it the mid-piece). Each s-bend will have a total length and total offset. Given a total length and offset, and fixed arc radius, I am trying to find a way to determine the required arc and mid-piece lengths so that I can cut them to size.

My work so far-
Constants:
The S-bend has length $L$ and offset $O$ (These change for different situations, essentially the input parameters).
The arc radius is $R$ (Based on available bends).
Unknowns: The 2 arcs and mid-piece will meet at a tangential angle $x$. The mid-piece will be length $M$.
For each arc: length = $R\sin(x)$, offset = $R(1-\cos(x))$
For the mid-piece: length = $M\cos(x)$, offset = $M\sin(x)$
The total length is then $$L = 2R\sin(x) + M\cos(x)\tag 1$$ and
the total offset $$O = 2R(1-\cos(x)) + M\sin(x)\tag 2$$
From (1): $M = \frac{L - 2R\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$
Subbing into (2): $O = 2R(1-\cos(x) + \frac{L - 2R\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$
And now I'm stuck! I want $x$. And then $M$.

Do you want the open ends of the arcs to be tangent to horizontal in the picture - that is, the directions at each end of the S-bend should be parallel?

Yes that is correct.

Try changing the input values here. [$\theta_1=\text{ your } x$]. Desmos regression uses numerical methods for solving, just as Ethan suggested.

Wolfram|Alpha does give some kind of solution. Have fun interpreting that ghastly mess!

Try dragging the blue dot in this Desmos graph for a more interactive experience.

Thank you. I'm new to all this and that Desmos is very useful.

You will need numerical methods to find $x$ from your final equation that calculates $O$ in terms of $x$. I suggest you put the right member in a spreadsheet and play with values for $x$ until the result matches $O$ closely enough.
Getting $M$ from equation (1) is then simple algebra.
In practice you may have to fudge some lengths to engineer the joints.

Yes I thought of making a simple app to just run through 0-90 and find the closest fit but it seemed rather inelegant to me.

@user120300 I think you will have to settle for inelegance.

Ha! I did end up making a dirty little app to do it, seems to work. My interest remains a bit though: in some drafting / sketching apps you can constrain similar sets of arcs / straights / etc. and I wonder if they process that recursively or they do indeed solve these types of equations.

Looking again, perhaps replacing $\cos x$ by $\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}$, isolating the square root and squaring might lead to a closed form solution. I haven't tried. Fortunately, you have a solution to your practical problem.

Thank you. That's the high-school / first year math I've long forgotten, first intuition is it will make it a solvable quadratic.

Worth a try. But it might be fourth degree in $\sin x$.
